# Facebook like & send buttons not picking up the thumbnail

Tags: facebook, button

I've added a facebook like button to a web page and everything works fine, except it doesn't pick up the thumbnail, or any image for that matter -- it posts only the text to the fb page with a blank instead of an image. The meta tag for the image looks like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.daisyworld.co.za/Birth_of_Modernity/einstein3.jpg" />
```

& the URL for the page is http://www.daisyworld.co.za/Birth_of_Modernity.htm"

I'v tried the process for a few of my other pages and the results are the same. I'm wondering if it's something related to my coding - I don't use an editor but write the code by hand - very basic HTML & CSS. The doctype looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

I've tried everything & looked everywhere for a possible explanation & came up as blank as the thumbnail.

I would appreciate it tremendously if someone can come up with an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you realise that the image is not available http://www.daisyworld.co.za/Birth_of_Modernity/einstein3.jpg

Comment: Your HTML also has some serious problems. http://validator.w3.org/